# Can't delete file from server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Ayo,

I'm using an FTP FileZilla solution and recently noticed that a few of my old directories are still on the server. I'm simply unable to erase those old directories because of one single file inside, that whenever I try to delete, says:
 *550 Forbidden filename*

[image: 500 Forbidden filename]

Does anyone know how to fix that?
thanks!

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Poraď mi jak to mám prosím přesunout?

Comment: "delete here, re-post there" – musis predtim zrusit prijeti odpovedi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a couple of potential workarounds for this, I believe it can be caused by "invisible" characters in the filename.

Firstly, try to rename the file (ideally in shell `mv 3.jpg deleteme.jpg`).

Secondly, you can try to create a PHP file in the directory which contains that file. Insert the code:

```
<?php
unlink('3.jpg');
?>
```

Then load the php file in a browser or execute in shell:

```
> php myphpfile.php
```

Comment: I took a look. The filename is actually " 3.jpg" ... note the space before "3". So try `unlink(' 3.jpg');`

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions. Vote them to be closed or migrated instead.